# Inform bower new plugin release

Tags: bower

I've created an open source javascript plugin. It is located on github public repository. When I want to release new version, I'm doing it with github features. My plugin is also indexed in bower repository. How to inform bower, that I have released new version of plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update any bower dependency using the "update" command. See below:

```
bower update <name>
```

Where  is the name of your bower package/dependency.
However, this is assuming that the semvar range provided in the bower.json configuration file allows the installation of the new (versioned) plugin.
As it is authored by you, I doubt very much it would be an issue.

If the above command doesn't work, you can always un-install it and reinstall it as follows:

```
bower uninstall <name>
bower install <name> --save-dev //or --save, this depends on how you installed it earlier.
```